# Python virtual env not activating

Tags: python, python-venv

For reference, I'm on Windows 11 using the Bash shell and have Python 3.9.2 installed.

I'm trying to create and activate a Python virtual environment using `venv` but when I activate it, nothing happens, but no error is given either. My understanding is that once I activate it, my prompt should change to reflect the environment I'm working in, and `where python` should show it in the virtual environment. Can anyone help clear this up for me?[image]

Answer (score 0):

Bash is unlike the normal command line interfaces on Windows. It uses the shell language, hence you'll not be able to activate it using the same procedure.
Since you generated the file from Windows,
to activate the virtual environment, run:

```
cd example_venv/Scripts
. activate
```

Take note of the space after the dot. It's very important for it to be included.

For those using Mac OS or Linux, you can just run:

```
source <path_to_venv>/bin/activate
```

where <path_to_venv> is the location of your virtual environment.

Comment: If you're using MinTTY/Mingw on Windows, you can execute your venv with source as well. `source example_venv/Scripts/activate`.